# Understanding URL that IdentityManager.findServerInfo() method expects?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, authentication, user-account

Does anyone have experience working with the IdentityManager object in the JS API 3.9?

I'm trying to understand what URL the findServerInfo() method expects.

I've tried the base REST url, and individual service URLs, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IdentityManager.findServerInfo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/identitymanager-amd.html#findserverinfo) expects a string, which needs to include a protocol, domain and subdomain. You don't need to include the path to a specific resource. Here's an example using the [Identity Manager sample](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/widget_identitymanager/), run this in the console:

```
esri.id.findServerInfo("https://servicesbeta.esri.com");
```

Path doesn't matter, so this:

```
esri.id.findServerInfo("https://servicesbeta.esri.com/nonsense/extra/stuff/");
```

Also works.